# Avoiding calling TypeScript user-defined type guard on every render

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm using a type guard, `isIData()` to verify that the data fetched from an API conforms to defined interface,

```js
const [data, setData] = useState<undefined | IData>(undefined);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
const [error, setError] = useState<boolean | string>(false);

useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchAPI() {
    let url = 'https://example.com/data.json';
    const res = await fetch(url);
    const data = await res.json();

    setData(data);
    setLoading(false);
    setError(false);
    return;
  }

  fetchAPI();
}, []);

return (
  <div>
    {loading && 'Loading...'}
    {!loading && error && 'An error occured'}
    {!loading &&
      !error &&
      isIData(data) &&
      <Chart data={data} />}
  </div>
);
```

As you can see above, in order for TypeScript to be satisfied that `data` has the correct format, I need to call it on every render.

This seems very inefficient. Is there a more efficient way to use type guards?

Comment: Explain what isIData does ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, TypeScript complains that the type of `Chart` props is `{data: IData}` while the type of `data` variable is `undefined | IData`, so you need to guard against:

```
<Chart data={undefined} />
```

In that case, TypeScript would be happy without calling `isIData()`, just checking for undefined:

```
{!error && data && <Chart data={data} />}
```

> Note: This would be similar even without TypeScript, when using `prop-types` library
>    `Chart.propTypes = {data: PropTypes.object.isRequired}`.

---

However, if you *want* to make sure the `data` has a correct shape, just not in every render, the best place is right after the fetch:

```
useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchAPI() {
    let url = 'https://example.com/data.json';
    const res = await fetch(url);
    const data = await res.json();

    if (isIData(data) {  // <--- here
      setData(data);
      setError(false);
    } else {
      setData(undefined);
      setError('data is not IData');
    }
  }
  fetchAPI()
}, []);

return (
  <div>
    {error && `An error occured: ${error}`}
    {!error && !data && 'Loading...'}
    {!error && data && <Chart data={data} />}
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Your example  of the code, like the author, does not contain Error handling. In my opinion  if the author makes such an error, this does not mean that you should do so too.

Comment: that's called [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - why should I introduce unrelated new concepts in my answer that would make it harder to understand? the other answer does not include proper error handling either, since `fetch` does not throw for non-200 http responses... and it's not including an error boundary for render errors.. and async functions just return a failed Promise anyway, not throwing during render, so the unhandled failed Promise would just print the error in the console...

Comment: I think it would be too much, show how to handle errors.

Comment: "In classic style, the author credits the reader with enough intelligence" -- Steven Pinker in The Sense of Style. If you have a question about error handling, @JAM, please post a new question.